# Php Notification system and websocket

Tags: php, websocket, push-notification, ratchet

i'm trying to develop a PHP notification service for a CRM used by my customers.

Scenario: an user add an appointment for a collegue, and this collegue has to receive a notification inside his CRM profile like, for example, Facebook did.

The structure is pretty simple: a PHP Server in listening with the client browser connected with Websockets.

Server: i'm using Ratchet - PHP WebSockets, i've followed the examples and started the server, server that is able now to accept connection and deliver messages to all clients connected or just to one receiver.

Client: a simple JS script, with Websocket connection and method, that handle all receiving messagges and notify all to the user connected.

My point is: i'm guessing to have the websocket client browser just for incoming messagge, i don't want to allow them to send nothing, the send part must be done by the server that has access to DB in this way:

1) FORM Appointment

2) Submit to the server and save it to DB, in this step a client PHP Websocket connect to the Ratchet server and send the notification to the receiver.

3) The Websocket of receiver receive the notification and alarm the customer.

The questions are:

- what can i use to do the step 2 with the PHP websocket client to connect with the Websocket server? is good to use Pusher interface like this example suggest: http://socketo.me/docs/push or  can i avoid using this system?
- how can i handle the idle time of websocket client ? a timer that send a ping like message to client for avoiding the dead of websocket?

-how handle possible down of client side or server side?

THanks to all of you!